# multiplication of matrices using while loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix, while-loop, multiplication

here below i have given multiplication of matrices in c language using for loop but can any help me make a more simplified version or can any help me make it using while loop

i want a simplified version

i want a code in while loop

:) just learning

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a[10][10], b[10][10], mul[10][10], r, c, i, j, k;
    system("cls");
    printf("enter the number of row=");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    printf("enter the number of column=");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("enter the first matrix element=\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("enter the second matrix element=\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("multiply of the matrix=\n");
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            mul[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
            {
                mul[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    //for printing result
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", mul[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kindly format your code. It's not readable. ```astyle``` or ```GNU indent``` would help.

Comment: Stay with the for loops, you're better of with. If you want to improve: Limit the scope of the loop variable to the loop itself by `for(int i = 0; i < r; ++i)`, dropping the previous declaration of `i` – `j` and `k` alike.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for reviewing working code. You might try [the code review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, this is actually *not* working code, at least not to my understandings. Matrices are all of same dimensions (note how the two input matrices are filled), and this would *only* work for the case of `r == c`...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service, either. It is for specific questions, not posting some code and having multiple people advise about improving it in diverse ways.

Answer (score 0):

It will not make code simpler only harder to read.

One of the loops example:

```
    printf("multiply of the matrix=\n");
    i = 0;
    while (i < r)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(j < c)
        {
            mul[i][j] = 0;
            k = 0;
            while(k < c)
            {
                mul[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```